# Get Soap Body using XPath and XML XPath Api

Tags: java, xml, soap, xpath

I use XML XPath API in my application

This is my soap request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tes="http://testwork/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <arg0>value</arg0>
          </tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to retrieve the body from this message, thus I want to have

```
<soapenv:Body>
          <tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <arg0>value</arg0>
          </tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
 </soapenv:Body>
```

My piece of code looks like

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
            XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xPath = xFactory.newXPath();
            Object result = xPath.compile("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
            log.info("result " + nodes);
```

But the result is  `result com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList@19f76837`

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`XPathConstants.NODESET` instructs the API to return a `NodeList` of the results it finds matching the query.

This is useful when you are expecting a variable number of matches.  You can iterate over the list...

```
for (int index = 0; index < nodes.getLength(); index++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(index);
    //...
}
```

If you are confident that you will only receive a single result (or you just want the first match), you can use `XPathConstants.NODE` instead

```
Object result = xPath.compile("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
Node node = (Node)result;
```

**Updated**

There's probably away to do this without doing the following, but name spaces do my head...

After you create the `factory, set it's name space awareness to`false`, then drop the node name space context from your search, for example...

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("Soap.xml"));

    XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath = xFactory.newXPath();
    Object result = xPath.compile("/Envelope/Body").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    System.out.println("Found " + nodes.getLength() + " matches");
    for (int index = 0; index < nodes.getLength(); index++) {
        Node node = nodes.item(index);
        System.out.println(node);
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | XPathExpressionException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: for (int index = 0; index < nodes.getLength(); index++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(index);
    //...
}

I added this piece of code to my application and found out that this code, where the nodes are iterated, is unreachable, is that possible that this is something wrong with xPath?

Comment: What do you mean "unreachable"

Comment: It's possible that xPath didn't find a match to your query

Comment: I was missing the factory.setNamespaceAware(false).